# OCaml list issue with cons operator

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

Here is my code:

```
let rec intersection l1 l2 res = 
  match l1 with
  | [] -> res
  | h1 :: t1 ->
    (
      match l2 with
      | [] -> []
      | h2 :: t2 ->
        if member h1 l2 = true then 
          intersection t1 l2 h1::res 
        else 
          intersection t1 l2 res
    )
```

the issue is with **h1::res** part it throws the following error:

> **Error:** This expression has type 'a list
> but an expression was expected of type 'a
> The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

But if I replace **h1::res** with **[h1]@res** then the code works, I am not getting the exact reason for this issue, please help.

**Note:** member is a custom function that returns true if an element belongs to the list l2 else false.

Comment: The problem is operator precedence. That line is parsed as `(intersection t1 l2 h1)::res`. You mean for it to be `intersection t1 l2 (h1::res)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the precedence in `intersection t1 l2 h1::res`. OCaml is trying to evaluate `intersection t1 l2 h1` and then cons that to `res`, which is of type `'a list. You need to specify operator precedence manually. You can either do

```
intersection t1 l2 (h1::res)
```

or, you can use the [application operator from the Pervasives module](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.02/htmlman/libref/Pervasives.html). As noted in the documentation, `g @@ f @@ x` is the same as `g (f (x))`

```
intersection t1 l2 @@ h1::res
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers and comments have correctly identified the issue, but it may helps someone reading this to see that in this situation, we can match on both lists and avoid the nested match expressions.

```
let rec member v = function 
  | [] -> false
  | x::xs when x = v -> true
  | _::xs -> member v xs

let rec intersection l1 l2 res =
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], _
  | _, [] -> res
  | h1::t1, _ when member h1 l2 -> 
    intersection t1 l2 @@ h1::res
  | h1::t1, _ -> intersection t1 l2 res
```

This still presents two problems.

### Performance

Performance is quadratic. We have a loop over `l2` within a loop over `l1`. It's not a problem for trivial sample sizes, but it scales very poorly.

```
intersection [1; 2] [2; 3] []
  member 1 [2; 3]
  member 1 [3]
  member 1 []
intersection [2] [2; 3] []
  member 2 [2; 3]
intersection [] [2; 3] [2]
[2]

intersection [1; 4; 3; 2; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] []
  member 1 [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 1 [4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 1 [6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 1 [7; 8; 9]
  member 1 [8; 9]
  member 1 [9]
  member 1 []
intersection [4; 3; 2; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] []
  member 4 [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 4 [4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
intersection [3; 2; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] [4]
  member 3 [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
intersection [2; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] [3; 4]
  member 2 [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 2 [4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 2 [6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 2 [7; 8; 9]
  member 2 [8; 9]
  member 2 [9]
  member 2 []
intersection [5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] [3; 4]
  member 5 [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 5 [4; 6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 5 [6; 7; 8; 9]
  member 5 [7; 8; 9]
  member 5 [8; 9]
  member 5 [9]
  member 5 []
intersection [] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] [3; 4]
[3; 4]
```

Increasing the sample size just a little bit dramatically increased the number of function calls required. Imagine if we'd used very large lists.

### Correctness

It doesn't give the right answer. Consider intersecting `[2; 2; 3]` and `[3; 1; 2]`. Because your function considers all of the second list on every recursive call, the result would be `[3; 2; 2]` rather than `[3; 2]`.

### A resolution

Checking for membership in the second list and removing seen members of the second list is hard because of how lists work in OCaml. The only cheap part of a list to get to is the first element and the tail. Anything within that tail requires work. And we don't know where in the second list the first element of the first list will occur.

*But we could.*

If we first sort both lists. Consider one of the earlier examples:

```
intersection [4; 3; 2; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] []
```

Let's make it:

```
intersection [2; 3; 4; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] []
```

Now we can compare first elements, so a run might look like:

```
intersection [2; 3; 4; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] []
intersection [3; 4; 5] [3; 4; 6; 7; 8; 9] []
intersection [4; 5] [4; 6; 7; 8; 9] [3]
intersection [5] [6; 7; 8; 9] [4; 3]
intersection [] [6; 7; 8; 9] [4; 3]
[4; 3]
```

And our example that produced incorrect result:

```
intersection [2; 2; 3] [1; 2; 3] []
intersection [2; 3] [2; 3] []
intersection [3] [3] [2]
intersection [] [] [3; 2]
[3; 2]
```

Yes, there is a cost to sorting the lists, but it's a one-time incurred penalty, and a good sorting routine will have O(n * log n) runtime complexity, which is much better than O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

Implementing this is straightforward using an inner function to which we pass the sorted lists.

```
let intersection lst1 lst2 =
  let rec intersect lst1 lst2 acc = 
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], _ | _, [] -> acc
    | x::xs, y::ys when x = y -> intersect xs ys (x::acc)
    | x::xs, y::ys when x > y -> intersect xs ys acc
    | x::xs, y::ys -> intersect xs lst2 acc
  in
  intersect (List.sort compare lst1) (List.sort compare lst2) []
```

Of course, we can now leverage modern OCaml and get rid of the explicit accumulator.

```
let intersection lst1 lst2 =
  let[@tail_mod_cons] rec intersect lst1 lst2 =
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], _ | _, [] -> []
    | x::xs, y::ys when x = y -> x :: intersect xs ys
    | x::xs, y::ys when x > y -> intersect xs ys
    | x::xs, y::ys -> intersect xs lst2
  in
  intersect (List.sort compare lst1) (List.sort compare lst2)
```